# How to convert dates into events?

Tags: workflow, outlook, events

I have a sharepoint site that features a variety of inputs, including a column for dates. It was created as a date list, but I cannot figure out how to get these dates to populate into a calendar. It seems I need to turn them into events, but i was unable to find a workflow for that. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just Create a calendar view 
on the time interval select the beggining date and the end date

then you can select what you want to see on each inidividual tile